# Can I handle user authentication with Firebase, but then securely pass authentication information to the server?

Tags: php, android, firebase, https, firebase-authentication

In my Android app, I have users authenticate using Firebase. I then will need my server to know which user is logged in to handle permissions. I am not very familiar with HTTPS, but can I simply send the user id of the authenticated user to the server as a POST parameter or in a cookie, and that will be secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you authenticate a user in you Android app and that user is sending a request to your server and you need to confirm that user's auth state and identity.

You will need to get the Firebase ID token. Use `currentUser.getIdToken`. This will give you the Firebase ID token. You can then post that to your server. It is recommended that you use an https connection. Also, it is better to pass the ID token in the post body or header of the request. On your server you will need to validate the ID token:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_a_third-party_jwt_library

Once you validate the ID token and its payload, you can parse its content and get the user id, `sub` field, identifying the authenticated user that sent the request.